# Filtering data in reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, reducers

I have the problem with sorting via reducer in ngrx.

The table was filled by the selector - ok great.

Now, I would like to implement a filter solution for table data - contains, start with, etc. And in my opinion, the best solution will be using dispatcher and action, and changes original data in reducer -> update via selector, which one was used in ngOnInit. But there is any possibility to come back to original data? When the filter will be empty? Or create in store duplicate data - original and filtered data, and switching between them?

Comment: Can you clarify this with some actual code?

Comment: There is standard data table with object array, f.e. [{name: string; data: data; name2: string etc...}] and I would like to filter per column....

Answer (score 1):

You can use *selectors* to select the original state and then modify according to your filter instead of duplicating the state itself.

If this is what you want, refer eg taken from [official documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors) which filters on some condition.

```
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.selectedUser;
export const selectAllBooks = (state: AppState) => state.allBooks;
 
export const selectVisibleBooks = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  selectAllBooks,
  (selectedUser: User, allBooks: Book[]) => {
    if (selectedUser && allBooks) {
      return allBooks.filter((book: Book) => book.userId === selectedUser.id);
    } else {
      return allBooks;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Uh great, it is good idea. But, when I wolud like to have "contains" filter. So the best way will be selector with props, when props will be "contains string". But I am wondering - how I will can change it dynamically - the props. Hmm, in ngOnInit will be one selector... but I will not change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to the selectors

```
export const selectAllBooks = (state: AppState) => state.allBooks;

export const selectBookById = createSelector(  
  selectAllBooks,
  (allBooks: Book[], props) => {
    const { id } = props;
    return allBooks.filter((book: Book) => book.userId === id);
}
```

In Component.ts in ngOnInit

```
this.books$ = this.store.pipe(selectBookById, { id: 123 });
```

Comment: Yes, but where multiple columns/filter? And I can set up two filter (two props?) and using filtering twice, by f.e. 1st and 3rd column contains

Comment: if i am understanding you correctly you can pass as many props as you want and use vanilla javascript to filter the results

e.g
`this.store.pipe(selectBookById, { id: 123, name: 'abc', date: '01/05/1983' })`